# Can alchemylanguage be used to analyze text without url?

Tags: ibm-watson, alchemyapi, watson

In the [demo](https://alchemy-language-demo.mybluemix.net/?cm_mc_uid=76807020536614756353286&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1477611376), it can analyze plain text
But in the API reference all [REST APIs](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/alchemy-language/api/v1/#combined-call) require url. And they don't seem to support analyze text directly. I tried to use text in a POST form anyway. But I got error.

```
{
    "status": "ERROR",
    "statusInfo": "invalid-url"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more a documentation issue, than a coding issue. In the documentation you will see three buttons. Select the Text one to get the documentation on Text calls.

[image]